# how to write a beautifully elegant linux command in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm running several web applications in my VM which is on Ubuntu 12.04.

I find myself typing the following very often when I ssh into my VM.

- `cd /var/virtual/app1.com/`
- `cd /var/virtual/app2.com/`
- `cd /var/virtual/app3.com/`

Each line represents a separate webapp root directory for me to perform certain instructions.

This is the lazy programmer asking if there is a way for me to type.

- `go_app1`
- `go_app2`
- `go_app3`

I know how to do the above using bash script.

but I will end up typing

```
./GoApp.sh -app app1
```

I want to make it more elegant by simply typing go_app1.

Advice?

**EDIT:**

I used the top-rated answer and I got this error message in Ubuntu.

https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/7336019

Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT2:**

I have rewritten the error into another question here at [command not found message when I try to add command in .bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19873430/80353).

Comment: You could get it to the point of `./GoApp.sh app1` and skip the option name...

Comment: My advice: if you want elegance, (1) choose more elegant names for your bash scripts and (2) put them in a directory which is in your $PATH. Do that, and you could type `go app1`, which would certainly count as elegant in my book.

Comment: The top rated answer is not always the best one. Please consider my answer, it fulfills 100% of your requirements!

Answer (score 3):

Defining an alias for each will certainly work. But since you have multiple desired shortcuts following a pattern, consider a function.

```
function go_app() { cd /var/virtual/app$1.com/; }
```

Usage:

```
go_app 1
```

Put the function definition in ~/.bashrc.

Comment: I like the approach, but wouldn't it be easier to just make the function `go_app() { cd  /var/virtual/app${1}.com/ }` and then use it as you indicated... (I think the OP was saying that `GoApp` was a shell script that took care of the `cd`ing...)

Comment: Yes. It seems the GoApp.sh was only a possible approach to solve the actual problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, I am using ubuntu. I keep getting this error message. https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/7336019

Answer (score 2):

You could use an alias by placing the below in your .bash_profile.

```
alias go_app1='cd /var/virtual/app1.com/'
```

After doing that, typing go_app1 should change your directory.

Comment: For linux users, it's the ~/.bashrc file.
Then, if you have 1000 apps directories, it's not a good solution. In this case, I prefer this one : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19720131/2900196 ;)

Comment: @IdrissNeumannn I tried your suggestion, but keep getting this command not found message. https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/7336019

Answer (score 2):

Would a search through the bash command-history be a good enough solution? I also often have to log into long directory structures, but I usually Ctrl-R through. E.g., if I had fairly recently cd-ed into your app1.com, I'd press
Ctrl-R
then type app1.com and the last command using app1.com would appear, at which point you press enter and you're done. If "cd" is not the one, you press Ctrl-R a few more times until it appears.

A bit more detail: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-bash-command-line-history/

Of course, this works only if you're concerned with how much you type, not if you're trying to do this programmatically, and only if the "cd" command was fairly recent in the list of commands that had "app1.com" (or any other short distinguishing pattern) explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the `$CDPATH` variable (in `bash`) to all the directories to be searched, including the current directory (at first), like:

```
 export CDPATH=.:/var/virtual:<other-dirs>
```

then I can just say:

```
 cd app1.com
```

given that, the directory names are short and I can type (rather than search them through the history)

Answer (score 0):

Improving on the corkin alias advice, but given flexibility of "naming" (with argument app1.com, app2.com, ...), this solution solves it with a single alias:

```
alias go_app='cd /var/virtual/; cd '
```

afterwards,

```
go_app app1.com
```

will `cd` into /var/virtual/app1.com/ . On naming: I would name it `cd_app` .
On a side note `go_app` without arguments will kick you back to your home (because the last command is `cd` without further arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `.bashrc`:

```
_make_go_apps() {
    local r=/var/virtual
    local d qd
    while read d; do
        printf -v qd '%q' "$r/$d"
        eval "go_${d%.com}() { cd -- $qd; }"
    done < <( find "$r" -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*/app[0-9]+\.com" -type d -printf '%f\n')
}
```

This will create functions `go_appX` with `X` a number such that the directory `/var/virtual/appX.com` exists, and this function, when called, will just `cd` into that directory.

Look (don't worry, I'm in a sandbox):

```
# mkdir -p /var/virtual/app{1..50}.com
# _make_go_apps
# go_app42
# pwd
/var/virtual/app42
```

Done!

If new directories are created, then just relaunch the function `_make_go_apps`.

This methods fulfills all the OP's requirements and is general enough to be able to cope with any number of directories.

`eval` is evil, but used in a safe way (read with sanitized variables, even though it's useless here; but if one day you want to generalize this method, you'll at least have this part correct).

**Do not try to generalize this method unless you absolutely know what you're doing: taking care of file names containing spaces, newlines, trailing newlines, etc.**

**Remarks.**

- If you want to change the location `/var/virtual`, just change the local variable `r`, making sure it's an absolute path.
- Tab completion of course works very well (and tab-tab will show you the possibilities).
- If you delete some directories, you might want a `_clean_go_apps` to only retain the relevant `go_appX`. One possibility is (it'll go in your `.bashrc`):

  ```
  clean_go_apps() {
      local r=/var/virtual
      local f
      while read _ _ f; do
          [[ $f =~ ^go_app[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || continue
          [[ -d $r/${f#go_}.com ]] && continue
          unset -f $f
      done < <(declare -F)
  }
  ```

  In this case, read the next part.

---

Then you'll realize it's not a good idea to have `/var/virtual` in two distinct places, so you'll want to use a global variable, and you'll end up with this in your `.bashrc`:

```
readonly _go_apps_basedir=/var/virtual
make_go_apps() {
    local d qd
    while IFS= read -d '' d; do
        printf -v qd '%q' "$_go_apps_basedir/$d"
        eval "go_${d%.com}() { cd -- $qd; }"
    done < <( find "$_go_apps_basedir" -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*/app[0-9]+\.com" -type d -printf '%f\0')
}

clean_go_apps() {
    local f
    while read _ _ f; do
        [[ $f =~ ^go_app[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || continue
        [[ -d "$_go_apps_basedir/${f#go_}.com" ]] && continue
        unset -f $f
    done < <(declare -F)
}

make_go_apps
```

I marked the variable `_go_apps_basedir` `readonly`, so that it's not changed inadvertently. This time I chose to use `IFS=''` and `-d ''` in the read, together with `-printf '%f\0'` in the `find` command, to show you how to do safe stuff when parsing the output of `find`.

---

I'm still concerned about the `find` in the `_make_go_apps` function, as it's not a 100% pure bash solution. Here's a 100% pure bash solution:

```
readonly _go_apps_basedir=/var/virtual
make_go_apps() {
    local f d qd saved_shopt
    saved_shopt=$(shopt -p)
    shopt -s extglob nullglob
    for d in "$_go_apps_basedir"/app+([[:digit:]]).com/; do
        f=${d#$_go_apps_basedir/}
        printf -v qd '%q' "$d"
        eval "go_${f%.com/}() { cd -- $qd; }"
    done
    eval "$saved_shopt"
}

clean_go_apps() {
    local f
    while read _ _ f; do
        [[ $f =~ ^go_app[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || continue
        [[ -d "$_go_apps_basedir/${f#go_}.com" ]] && continue
        unset -f $f
    done < <(declare -F)
}

make_go_apps
```

---

**Sorry** for this long an messy post... I was more or less thinking while typing (not good to do!), and I never wanted to erase the previous parts, as they contain interesting stuff.

---

**Edit**. Now, to make this post even longer, here's the same, but that will create a `go_X` function for every directory `X.com` inside `/var/virtual`, such that `X` only contains the characters: `[0-9a-zA-Z\-\._]`. Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
readonly _go_apps_basedir=/var/virtual
make_go_functions() {
    local f d qd saved_shopt
    saved_shopt=$(shopt -p)
    shopt -s extglob nullglob
    for d in "$_go_apps_basedir"/+([[:alpha:][:digit:]\-\._]).com/; do
        f=${d#$_go_apps_basedir/}
        printf -v qd '%q' "$d"
        eval "go_${f%.com/}() { cd -- $qd; }"
    done
    eval "$saved_shopt"
}

clean_go_apps() {
    local f
    while read _ _ f; do
        [[ $f =~ ^go_.+$ ]] || continue
        [[ -d "$_go_apps_basedir/${f#go_}.com" ]] && continue
        unset -f $f
    done < <(declare -F)
}

make_go_functions
```

Comment: I understand why you would not want erase your earlier parts, but could you write a concise summary of the answer you would suggest? Right now, I cannot be sure which part of your answer I should adopt.

Comment: @KimSia The bottom part is great: put it at the bottom of your `.bashrc` and when you open a new terminal you'll have all the functions `go_app1`, `go_app2`, etc. ready to use that will directly take you where you  want. You'll also have the function `clean_go_apps` to remove the corresponding functions after deleteing a directry. If you want to then create the functions `go_appX` after creating a directory, just launch `make_go_apps`. `:)`

Comment: I want to change it so that it works even for non-digits. e.g. /var/virtual/abcd/ I apologize. but your bash script is a bit intimidating for a beginner like myself to edit.

Comment: @KimSia It's very difficult if you start changing the original requirements! So you'd like a function `go_X` for any `X.com` a directory inside `/var/virtual`? See the last part!

Comment: @KimSia it works for all directories that end in `.com`. Now you _really_ want to have a function `go_X` for every directory `X` in `/var/virtual`? then I'm sorry, because this really contradicts your OP. Your OP specifies `app1.com`, `app2.com`, ... and you wanted functions `go_app1`, `go_app2`, etc. If I now answer your latest requirement, it means that instead you'll have functions `go_app1.com`, `go_app2.com`, etc. I could now make a special treat for the ones ending in `.com` and the other ones, but I just can't be bothered since after that you'll change again your requirements.

Comment: @KimSia Please _learn_ to _ask_ the _right_ questions. (and before that, maybe you'll need to have a _clear idea_ of what you _really want_). Computer logic needs rigorous thinking. Not "oh it will be nice if the computer could understand what I have in mind at every moment and just do it".

Comment: Cool. I respect that.