# command not found message when I try to add command in .bashrc

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I asked a question at [how to write a beautifully elegant linux command in bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19720095/80353)

And when I tried the suggestion, I got the following error message.

```
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.2.3 final 0
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
Exception information:

unsupported locale setting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 24, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 69, in main
    enable_i18n()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 40, in enable_i18n
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/locale.py", line 541, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

This is what I currently write in my .bashrc

```
source .bashrc
export LC_CTYPE="utf-8"
function go_app() { cd /var/virtual/$1/; }
```

Here is my /var/www directory

```
www-data@ubuntu:~$ ls -la
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data  4096 Nov  9 15:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root      4096 Nov  8 09:51 ..
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data 19657 Nov  7 23:24 .bash_history
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data    82 Nov  9 15:03 .bashrc
drwx------  2 www-data www-data  4096 Aug  7 19:28 .cache
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data  4096 Aug  9 19:19 .composer
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data     6 Aug  8 11:48 .mysql_history
-rw-------  1 root     root        50 Nov  9 15:08 .nano_history
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Aug  7 20:19 .ssh
```

**EDIT:**

New .bashrc

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
function go_app() { cd /var/virtual/$1/; }
```

Error message:

```
go_app: command not found
```

Comment: Why do you have `source .bashrc` in your `.bashrc`? Isn't that recursively loading itself?

Comment: It was a fix recommeded by someone in my original question. I have now removed it. and changed `export LC_CTYPE="utf-8"` to `export LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"` Now getting just `go_app: command not found`

Comment: And does the latter fix the problem, if you open a new terminal?

Comment: So the original problem is fixed then.

Comment: I'm guessing you put `source .bashrc` in the wrong file.

Comment: I am still getting the command not found message though. See my updated question

Answer (score 25):

A bad WSL upgrade messed up some of my file permissions. None of the other answers worked for me, but this did:

```
sudo chmod o+r /var/lib/command-not-found/commands.db
```

Comment: After cis hardening on ubuntu 20.04 this issue happened for me and by this fix my issue resolved.

Answer (score 9):

This should fix the "Sorry, command-not-found has crashed!..." issue:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 # sudo required on ubuntu 20.04
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Answer (score 5):

If any of the above solutions don't work, it means "command-not-found" utility itself is misconfigured.

Simply remove the utility,

```
sudo apt purge command-not-found
```

and install again,

```
sudo apt install command-not-found
```

Comment: That worked for me but it also required `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/command-not-found` in between and `sudo apt update` after the install.

Answer (score 3):

this is better with a final asterisk :

```
sudo chmod o+r /var/lib/command-not-found/commands.db*
>----------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: yes !
it extends root only access to user read access

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing `export LC_CTYPE="utf-8"` to `export LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"`? The latter references a valid locale name on my system. You can see the valid locale names on your system by running `locale -a`.

Comment: Still getting the command not found statement. See my updated question

Comment: I'm guessing you put `source .bashrc` in the wrong file. As I said, it doesn't make sense for .bashrc to source itself. Try putting it in the right file.

Comment: You can see my /var/www directory in my question. Which file should i put source.bashrc in?

Comment: I don't know, because I'm not the guy who told you to put it in! Maybe ask that guy!